# Sort table from side menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, html-table

It might sounds weird.
I would like to know if it's possible to sort a table by clicking on the side menu link and not from the table header.

[image]

I know that we can sort, make pagination... inside the table by using some jQuery libraries.

But my request here is to sort from the side menu and not from the table header.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>blabla</th>
     <th>blabla</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>blabla</td>
    <td>blabla</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: nothing yet, I have no idea how can I do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tablesorter's sorton event:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mysortable").tablesorter();

  $("#navigator div").click(function() {
    var column = $(this).data("column") - 1;
    $("#mysortable").trigger("sorton", [[[column, 0]]]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.19.1/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.19.1/css/theme.default.css"/>

<div id="navigator" style="float:left; max-width:200px;">
  <div data-column="1">Sort Column One</div>
  <div data-column="2">Sort Column Two</div>
  <div data-column="3">Sort Column Three</div>
</div>

<table id="mysortable" class="tablesorter" style="float:right; max-width:400px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Z</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Y</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>X</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

This might give u a idea on how to do it mate..

```
function sortColumn(c,n){
  var rows = $('#mytable tbody  tr').get();

  rows.sort(function(a, b) {

  var A = $(a).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
  var B = $(b).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();

  if(A < B) {
    return -1*c;
  }
  if(A > B) {
    return 1*c;
  }
  return 0;
  });

  $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    $('#mytable').children('tbody').append(row);
  });
}


 var sln = 1;
$("ul li").click(function(){
    sln *= -1;
    var n = $("ul li").index(this);
    sortColumn(sln,n);
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/geonbs72/)

Answer (score 1):

here is how

```
function sort_rows(col_num, ascending) {
  var $rows = $('#'+table_id+' tr').not( function(i,e) {
      return $(e).find('th').length > 0;
    } );
  var sort_values = [];
  var indx_values = [];
  $rows.each( function (i,e) {
      sort_values.push( $(e).find('td:nth-child('+col_num+')').text() );
      indx_values.push(sort_values.length-1);
    } );

  var ordering;
  if (ascending) {
    ordering = function (a,b) { return a < b; };
  } else {
    ordering = function (a,b) { return a > b; };
  }

  var k = 0, val = sort_values[0];
  for(var i = sort_values.length-1; i > 0; i-=1) {
    for(var j = i; j >= 0; j-=1) {
      if (ordering(sort_values[j], val))
        val = sort_values[j];
        k = j;
      }
    }
    var temp = sort_values[j];
    sort_values[j] = sort_values[i];
    sort_values[i] = temp;
    var temp = indx_values[j];
    indx_values[j] = sort_values[i];
    indx_values[i] = temp;
  } 

  list_$rows = [];
  $rows.each( function (i,e) { list_rows.push($(e).clone()); } );
  $rows.remove();
  for(var i = 0; i < sort_values.length; i+=1) {
    $('#'+table_id).append( list_$rows[indx_values[i]] );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try it and let you know